# Ask for Facebook permissions with dialog box only

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

This code is used to get facebook data from users of my codeigniter application that I would be launching in a facebook page tab.

```
require_once('facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php');

        $facebook= new Facebook(array(
          'appId' => $this->config->item('app_id'),
              'secret' => $this->config->item('app_secret'),
              'allowSignedRequest' => false,
        ));

        $_REQUEST += $_GET;
        $user = $facebook->getUser();

        if ($user) {
          try {

            $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me?fields=picture.width(100).height(100),first_name,last_name,username,email');

          } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            $user = null;
          }
        } else {
           $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
                'scope' => 'email'
            ));
             redirect($login_url, 'refresh');
        }
```

I want it so that if the user is already logged into facebook that when they open the tab to use the app, instead of being asked to log in, that the dialog box come up asking for permissions. I need email permissions.

How do i skip the login to get permissions step if a user is already logged into Facebook, and just have the dialog box appear asking for permissions?

Comment: The dialog for logging in and asking for permissions is on and the same. If you don’t want to _redirect_ the user to the dialog page, but have a nice dialog box overlayed on the page instead, then use `FB.login` out of the JS SDK.

Comment: @CBroe would this just ask users to click ok. The current code above sends the user to a login page where they must enter their Facebook creds, then a dialog box appears asking to ok the app. Would the javascript sdk bypass the need to login to get email and just ask with the dialog

Comment: They only have to input their credentials if they are not logged into Facebook already. And that’s of course the same no matter what version of calling the login dialog you use.

Comment: ok. Will work some more on it tonight. Will keep you posted.